# ASP.NET , C# how to write this sql command

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sqlcommand

How can I write this code in asp.net c# code behinds?

Wwhat I'm trying to do is to select all rows in `invoicetable` with `orderno` that is equal to current `session` and deduct the inventory of my `inventorytable` from `invoicetable qty that matches their itemid's.

```
SqlCommand cmd = 
    new SqlCommand("UPDATE inventorytable 
                    JOIN invoicetable ON inventorytable.ItemID = invoicetable.ItemID 
                    SET inventorytable.inventory = inventorytable.inventory-invoice.QTY 
                    WHERE invoicetable.No='" + Convert.ToInt32(Session["invoiceno"]) + "'"
                    , con);

InsertUpdateData(cmd);
```

Comment: The code you provide is for an update statement.  Is there other SQL you want evaluated?

Comment: Where are your items IDs. have you put also in session variable ?

Comment: Also, the snippet you provided has some pretty serious security issues.

Comment: Have a look into parameters.

Comment: Yes I am trying to UPDATE the inventorytable by reducing  the inventory column of each item by deducting  the invoicetable column QTY

Comment: What SQL dialect is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update query is not formed correctly, and you should be using parameterized SQL. Try using something like this

```
var sqlQuery = 
    @"UPDATE inventorytable 
         SET inventorytable.inventory = inventorytable.inventory-invoice.QTY 
        FROM inventorytable
             INNER JOIN invoicetable ON inventorytable.ItemID = invoicetable.ItemID 
       WHERE invoicetable.No=@invNo";

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(CONN_STR))
{
   var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
   sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invNo", Session["invoiceno"].ToString());
   sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I typed this without VS in front of me, so let me know if there are any syntax issues

Comment: I tried your code and It works. You save me a lot of time, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
    var n = Session["invoiceno"] != null ? Convert.ToInt32(Session["invoiceno"]) : 0;

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(CONN_STR))
{
    conn.Open();
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM invoicetable WHERE orderno = @n";
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
    cmd.Connection = conn ;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", n);

    using(var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(dr.Read())
        {
            //loop through DataReader
        }
        dr.Close();
    }
}
```